# Python pandas. Взять данные из определенных столбцов и посчитать

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет. Продолжаю изучение pandas и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
У меня есть файл csv в котором есть n кол - во столбцов (ну и значения в этих столбцах). Есть столбец(признак) **race** - в нём указана национальность человека.
есть столбец **sex** - в нём указан пол (Male - мужчина; Female - женщина) и есть столбец **age** - возраст.
Задача следующая: получить максимальный возраст *мужчин* расы Amer-Indian-Eskimo.
Просто получить максимальный возраст и мужчин и женщин не проблема :

```
print(df[df['race'] == 'Amer-Indian-Eskimo'] ['age'].max())
```

Вообщем не могу посчитать максимальный возраст именно мужчин. Не понимаю как указать в коде что нужно учитывать значение **Male** из столбца **sex**

Comment: На будущее - постарайтесь приводить в вопросах по Pandas [примеры входных и выходных данных](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо что поправили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ещё один вариант решения, который выглядит немного более читабельным:

Данные:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
  race sex  age
0    a   m   11
1    a   f   23
2    a   f   45
3    b   m   56
4    b   f   39
5    c   f   66
```

Решение:

```
In [9]: df.query("race=='a' and sex=='f'")['age'].max()
Out[9]: 45
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [52]: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\adult.data.csv')

In [53]: df.query("race=='Amer-Indian-Eskimo' and sex=='Male'")['age'].max()
Out[53]: 82
```

Comment: Да так и вправду лучше. Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: Вот такую вот ошибку выдал: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'bool'> given   . У столбца age у меня значение int64

Comment: можете привести небольшой пример данных, который позволит воспроизвести эту ошибку?

Comment: Я так понимаю ему не нравится тип данных столбцов sex и race https://yadi.sk/i/T5m20vOm5Lkh1w  . Нужно их преобразовать в  строки судя по ошибке. Делаю так ничего не помогает https://yadi.sk/i/Rz4JQ7hUPmzX0Q

Comment: Забыл сам файл скинуть https://yadi.sk/d/qG6JiaqlWgBV5A

Comment: @IT-KOT, у меня все прекрасно работает - смотрите UPDATE. Я не смог воспроизвести ошибку... Кстати преобразовывать `sex` и `race` в строки не нужно - они и так уже строки

Comment: Он ссылается в ошибке на данную строчку в библиотеке пандаса https://yadi.sk/i/AAFFmatjv-DDfA

Comment: @IT-KOT, вы можете выложить стек ошибки в виде текста __в теле вопроса__? Для того чтобы скачивать данные с `yadi.sk` мне каждый раз приходиться выходить из корпоративной сети, чтобы обойти firewall...

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "task.py", line 53, in <module>
    print(df.query('race' == 'Amer-Indian-Eskimo' and 'sex' == 'Male')['age'].max())
  File "D:\YandexDisk\Home\Python\Project\Test\Hbr bd pd\v\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3085, in query
    raise ValueError(msg.format(type(expr)))
ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'bool'> given`

Comment: @IT-KOT, скопируйте код из моего ответа "как есть" без модификаций и попробуйте его запустить... ;)

Comment: Прошу меня извинить за ложную тревогу. Вот ваш код в моём редакторе: `print(df.query("race=='Amer-Indian-Eskimo' and sex=='Male'")['age'].max())`  а вот как я изначально его написал у себя `print(df.query('race' == 'Amer-Indian-Eskimo' and 'sex' == 'Male')['age'].max())`  . Теперь всё работает.  Вообщем я допустил ошибку синтакиса

Answer (score 2):

Так вроде сам разобрался.

```
print(df[(df['race'] == 'Amer-Indian-Eskimo') & (df['sex'] == 'Male')]['age'].max())
```

Поправьте если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Да всё верно. Разобрался)